# Какой принцип обработки очереди изменеий setState() в React.Component?

Tags: reactjs

1) Я правильно понимаю, что setState() кладет в очередь (или сводит, объединяя в один объект) необходимые изменения и при срабатывании какого-то тригера эта группа изменений применяется на стейт?

2) Если да, то чем является этот триггер? В чем выигрышь в производительности?

3) Вызов render() происходит синхронно в момент вызова setState() или только после обработки изменений (т.е. обработали несколько изменений пакетом и только один раз вызвали render)?

Спасибо!

Comment: Я так понимаю что при вызове setState вызывается функция render и в зависимости от state выводит новое виртуальное под-дерево. Потом деревья сравниваются и если есть изменения то виртуальное дерево именно в тех местах где есть изменения обновляет dom.

Comment: Чисто с логической позиции тригер на обновление вызывается когда все асинхронные вызовы, которые были затронуты функцией завершатся.

Comment: Это надо смотреть сорцы. В документации написано (было), что на очерёдность сейСтейт полагаться не стоит

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js#L53